# Reset /usr/local/bin ownership as rootless on macos ventura

Tags: macos

I set `/usr/local/bin` directory using the `sudo chown -R root /usr/local/bin` for the permission on the current user session.

Before I set this permission, I was getting the following output when I used the `ls -ld /usr/local/bin` command:

```
 $ myuser> ls -ld /usr/local
 drwxr-xr-x 9 root  wheel  288 Feb 16 00:03 /usr/local/bin
```

Now I get the following output with the above command:

```
 $ myuser> ls -ld /usr/local/bin                         
 drwxr-xr-x@ 16 root  wheel  512 Feb 16 00:03 /usr/local/bin
```

What can I do to undo the change?

Comment: The output from the `ls` commands doesn't make sense; the "before" example is missing the mode bits, link count, owner, group, etc, and neither should have "$ > " at the beginning.

Comment: Did it really just list the name, even though you used the `-l` flag (which should make `ls` print all the other info too)? Did it give any error messages?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Wow, you're right. In the first example I accidentally used "I" instead of "L" and shared this output. Thank you for correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run :

```
sudo chown -R $(id -un):$(id -gn) /usr/local/bin
```

or even better :

```
sudo chown -R $(id -un):$(id -gn) /usr/local/*
```

in case you have other directories in `/usr/local` which belong to `root`.

Comment: Now, my `ls -ld /usr/local/bin` output is `drwxr-xr-x@ 16 myuser  staff  512 Feb 16 00:03 /usr/local/bin` Do you think this output is correct?

Comment: I think it's ok, do you still have problems ?

Comment: As I mentioned above, it still says session username instead of root, "@" end of the permissions and a different number of hard links:
`drwxr-xr-x@ 16 my-user-name staff 512 Feb 16 00:03 /usr/local/bin`